# PHP hyperlink wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, echo

I am trying to create a hyper link to another url/website from body text of my wordpress theme, the link works but when I click it, it takes me to 404 page instead of the website that I am creating the link to

```
<?php echo "<a href='$website_url'"?> target='_blank'>text</a>
```

Comment: worked with http:// Michal,

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Your $website_url variable, shuld starts with "http://" other ways you get local link.